# How do I use a style selector to select custom controls in Avalonia?

Tags: avaloniaui

I want to make a Play-Pause Toggle Button in Avalonia with Material.Icon.Avalonia packge.

My approach is to use the `style selector` to change the `MaterialIcon`'s `Kind` property based on the `Togglebutton`'s `IsChecked` property, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
xmlns:materialIcons="clr-namespace:Material.Icons.Avalonia;assembly=Material.Icons.Avalonia"
```

```xml
<ToggleButton Width="40"
              Height="40"
              Command="{Binding PlayOrPauseVideoCommand}"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsPlaying}">
    <ToggleButton.Styles>
        <Style x:SetterTargetType="{x:Type materialIcons:MaterialIcon}"
               Selector="ToggleButton:checked materialIcons:MaterialIcon">
            <Setter Property="Kind" Value="Pause" />
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Styles>
    <Grid>
        <materialIcons:MaterialIcon x:Name="PlayorPauseIcon"
                                    Width="30"
                                    Height="30"
                                    Kind="Play" />
    </Grid>
</ToggleButton>
```

There is tow problems.

1. If I use `Selector="ToggleButton:checked materialIcons:MaterialIcon"` instead of `Selector="ToggleButton:checked #PlayorPauseIcon"`.
   `Avalonia error AVLN:0004: Unable to resolve type materialIcons from namespace https://github.com/avaloniaui` will be occured during build the project.
   **Is there an another way to select a custom control instand of naming it and use `Selector="#ControlName"`**
2. Even though I used `Selector="ToggleButton:checked #PlayorPauseIcon"`.  and no errors occurred during build the project, The selector still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a namespace in Selector markup, you need to use a pipe symbol rather than a colon. Colons are instead used for pseudo-classes to be consistent with the way they are used in CSS, which inspired AvaloniaUI.

```xml
<Style Selector="ToggleButton:checked materialIcons|MaterialIcon">
```